# replace %25 in url with space using coldfusion using cfhttp

Tags: coldfusion

I am making a cfhttp get call to another page. I am passing the url variable using cfhttpparam as shown below. But when I run the page, the url is rendered as shown in the image. I need to replace %25 to be able to get the correct url string. Can someone tell me what is wrong with the code?

```
<cfset vpName = "Abc def  F hig K xyz" /> I want %20 in the spaces in the name here. But it is rending as show in the image![enter image description here][1]
<cfset urlvar = URLEncodedFormat("#vpName#")>

<!--- <cfoutput>#urlvar#</cfoutput>
 --->

 <cfhttp url="https://abc.com/xyz/EM2/LTMR.cfm" method="get" username="abcd" password="password" >   

 <cfhttpparam type="url" name="LTMX" value="#urlvar#">

</cfhttp> 


<cfset myDocument = cfhttp.fileContent>

<cfoutput>#myDocument#</cfoutput>
```

URL is rendered as

abc.com/LTMR.cfm?LTMX=Andre%2520Fuetsch%2520%2520F%2520Shelly%2520K%2520Lazzaro

Comment: Your question is unclear, but seeing `%2520` probably means your URLs are double-encoded. (`%25` is the encoded version of `%`). The solution being to only encode it once, not twice. (It may be that cfhttparam is doing it once, so your UrlEncodedFormat call is unnecessary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The %25 is what the "[URLEncodedformat()](http://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/urlencodedformat)" is *supposed* to do - replace spaces (etc) with the appropriate encoded sequence - and as Peter said the `<cfhttpparam>` does this automatically - so you should change this;

```
<cfset urlvar = URLEncodedFormat("#vpName#")>
```

to be this...

```
<cfset urlvar = vpName/>
```

Although you could of course simply pass in the `vpName` instead of creating a completely separate variable for it.